# How to get the current file name in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am having an ansible script. It calls other scripts using include module.

I need to get the current file name in a variable.

For ex:

```
 - include: Run-Config889.yml
```

Inside Run-Config889.yml, i need to get the file name Run-Config889.yml in a variable.

Whether any built-in variable is there to find the current file name? if so what it is?

Comment: Idk about a starightforward way to do it. I guess you could use roles instead as they do give you a special var named "role_name". The workaround you could use if you don't want to use roles, is to maybe define the names of the .yml in variables. Save the name in a file in your localhost, and then execute the "include". So your included playbook, can then read the name from your file in your localhost. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @SebastiánGreco Currently i am using variables to store the file name and use it. But in some places i need file name still.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current playbook file name with :

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    playbook_absoluteName: "{{ (lookup('file', '/proc/self/cmdline') | regex_replace('\u0000',' ')).split() | select('match','^.*[.]ya?ml$') | list | first }}"
    playbook_baseName: "{{ playbook_absoluteName | basename }}"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: item
    loop:
      - "{{ playbook_absoluteName }}"
      - "{{ playbook_baseName }}"
...
```

This was inspired by [this blog article](https://iautomatelinux.wordpress.com/2019/03/29/ansible-get-current-playbook-name/), with minor/cosmetics improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about any built-in variable but there are 2 options I can think of.

**Option 1**

You can pass variables to included files like so:

*main.yml*

```
---

- include: Run-Config889.yml file_name_variable="Run-Config889.yml"
```

**Option 2**

Set the variable in any of the vars files used by the play. All defined variables in a play are inherited by subsequent include statements.

*sample-vars.yml*

```
---

file_name_variable: "Run-Config889.yml"
```

---

Using the variable.

*Run-Config889.yml*

```
---

- name: Display variable
  debug:
    msg: File name {{ file_name_variable }}
```