# How to get general information about a file, such as the filename?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a directory of files I'm looping through and I need to get the filename and possibly other information. The `win_stat` module I think uses PowerShell, so it gets the `name`, `basename`, `path`, I think last modified date, etc. Is there a comparable module for use on Linux? I tried the `stat` and `find` modules, but they only get the full path.

I've also tried different filters, like this one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240812/7771746):

```yaml
lookup('file', item.path) | regex_replace('\u0000',' ')).split() | select('match','^[a-z-_/]*[.]y[a]*ml') | list | first | basename
```

But this throws an error, or returns nothing. I've also tried just passing the path to `basename`:

```yaml
item.path | basename
```

But this also does nothing.

This seems like a super simple thing, so I don't understand why it's so complicated to even need a long filter/replace like that.

I suppose I could just split the path and grab the last element:

```yaml
item.path | split('/') | last
```

But this seems messy and I would think Ansible would have a better way to get this information about a file?

So what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a lot you are explaining in the question and you even explained your trial, but please remember that a simple example input / desired output is most of the times worth a thousand words. Your whole question could be supersized to _"I have `/path/to/file.ext` and need to extract `file.ext`, how can I do this in Ansible?"_

Comment: On the actual question, then. `basename` **is** indeed the filter you want to use. Claiming _"does nothing"_ is of little help, sadly. Could you show us a `debug` return of `item.path` and of `item.path | basename` so we can have a sense of what is really happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the way you get the list of your files and the format of this list.
You can try this approach :

```
- find:
    paths: /tmp/test
    patterns: "*.txt"
  connection: local
  register: list_files

- name: Loop files
  debug:
    msg: "Filename {{ item.path | basename }} and size {{ item.size }}"
  loop: "{{ list_files.files }}"
```

You get the **path** and use the **basename** filter.

Just take care the **connection: local** in find task if you want to search files on remote host you should remove it.
If you are looking on the machine which is executing ansible you can keep it